# Why does Google Analytics log a user logging in as an exit?

Tags: google-analytics, drupal, tracking

I have custom event tracking set up in Google Analytics that tracks when a visitor registers on the site. The tracking is working fine. However, GA is showing that 100% of users "exit" the site after registering. They aren't exiting however, they are just getting logged in.

Is there some reason why a user creating a session by logging in would cause GA to lose track of the visitor and think a new user had arrived? Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically they have exited the site and started a new session as a logged in user - GA is tracking them correctly from the sound it.

You would need to use custom tracking to follow them through end to end.

Comment: @Justin 8 more?

Comment: I can't just say thanks, it says "8 more to go" for characters to enter.